# Initializing array of structs inside a mapping of structs - "UnimplementedFeatureError

Tags: struct

I have two structs

```
struct Vote {
  address from;
  uint256 rep;
  bool vote;
}

struct Pool { 
  address from;  
  string tokenSymbol;
  string name; 
  uint256 timeout;  
  string evidence;  
  Vote[] votes;
}

mapping(uint256 => Pool) validationPool;
```

How do I initialize an empty array of votes while creating a new Pool Struct?

```
    validationPool[proposalIndex] = Pool({
        from: msg.sender, tokenSymbol:_tokenSymbol,
        name:_name, 
        timeout: now + 180, 
        evidence:_evidence, 
        votes: new Vote[](0) });
```

I see the compilation error :

UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct DemoContract.Vote memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
What does it mean and how do I initialize an array of structs inside another struct?

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for the right way of doing it but found a work around. Here, there was no value associated with this proposalIndex in validationPool.

```
    Pool storage pool = validationPool[proposalIndex];
    pool.from = msg.sender;
    pool.name = _name;
    pool.timeout = now + 180;
    pool.evidence = _evidence;
```